# Do Predators "adopt" other species and teach them to be Warriors or Hunters?

Tags: predator-series, the-predator

The *Predator* franchise has a long history of hunting deadly creatures which can defend themselves, including the Xenomorphs, and humans. On several occasions, we see Predators [Yautja] present humans with weapons or "trophies" after surviving a hunt, or killing worthy opponents in combat. The 2018 movie, *The Predator*, saw one Yautja attempting to deliver armor to humans, attempt to take a human child back to the planet, and revealed they had even had a heavy amount of human DNA within their own genome.

Are there canon examples then of Predators literally *adopting* humans into their clans and raising them in their ways?

Comment: https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Machiko_Noguchi

Comment: What do yiou mean by canon? There's only a few films in which they appear, and then largely as two-dimensional baddies.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, a few films, but from what I gather there's a whole _world build_ around them; culture, traditions, norms, customs, tribes, behaviors. We saw them "tattooed" Alexa in **Aliens vs Predator**, effectively marking her as one of their own warriors (I guess?) And its been seen that they kidnapped humans and took them to a "Game Preserve" planet before. The presence of human DNA on film _may_ indicate there have been attempts to cross breed, and they obviously have respect for humans as warriors. So I wondered if (anywhere in the franchise) if humans had been taken into their society.

Comment: If you just mean the films then there's almost nothing about their culture, period. If you're including the books and games, there's more, but it's often self-contradictory, as Extended Universe stuff tends to be

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, of course we could include the extended universe; that's where a lot of lore comes from.  Them working with humans seems to fit into the 2018 film, though. why else would they provide that armor at the end?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the existing movies, there is nothing mentioning Predators adopting humans, however it has happened at least once in the comic book series, which predates the movies:

**Machiko Noguchi** (野口真千子), was a Chigusa Corporation employee and the administrator in charge of the Prosperity Wells colony on Ryushi. Unfortunately, this planet has been selected as a hunting ground for a young Yautja (the proper name for the Predator species): Predators plant a few xenomorph (Alien) eggs on a planet and send young warriors to prove themselves in the hunt. Unfortunately for both humans and Yautja, a Queen hatches from one of the eggs and quickly both the hunting party as well as human colonists are facing a huge swarm of Aliens.

Machiko oversees the evacuation and then helps one of the predators to kill the aliens - together they manage to kill a queen, however, the predator, now mortally wounded marks her as a warrior:

[image]

When the Predator ship arrives, Machiko is invited to join in and given honours of a hunter. However, with time she has to fight more and more prejudice and while she manages to keep proving her skills, she is demoted to being just a servant. When she finds out that on the current hunt Yautja attacked a human colony, she betrays Predators by releasing imprisoned on the ship Alien Queen and helps to kill the hunters.

[More info at AVP wiki](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Machiko_Noguchi) (Link already provided by @Valorum)

Comment: I remember this story arc from one of the books (novels), not the comic books. I read it a long time ago though and can't remember the details. I wonder if it was the same story...